# GUI upgrade to 19.10 stuck on a Configuring Secure Boot Window

Tags: upgrade, 19.04, 19.10, gui

[image]

I'm trying to update from Ubuntu 19.04 to Ubuntu 19.10 and the upgrade ran smoothly until it encountered the window in the image attached. I don't seem to be able to interact with this window in any way. Can I move past this step somehow? Can I stop the installation and revert back to 19.04? Can I stop the upgrade and do it in the command line so I can interact with this prompt once I get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to Navigate to `OK`.

Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept.

Comment: Thanks! The Esc key also directly moves to a window where you can type in your password.